# No exported member error in VS Code, but not in console

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typeorm

I have one NestJS project (project A), and one module, which uses `@nestjs/typeorm` and `typeorm` package.

My another NestJS project (project B), will use this module. However, there is one problem. In project B, I have entities, and this entities should have annotations (decorators), that are defined in typeorm package. I can use this decorator if I install package typeorm inside my project B. However, because of this, typeorm can have different version in project A and project B. So best version would be, to re-export all this `typeorm` stuff, in my project A, together with its corresponding module, right?

So I re-export it like this in project A

```
export * from 'typeorm';
```

If I ran this from console, it is working ok (I haven't detected any abnormal behavior). However, in my IDE (Visual Studio Code), this is underlined, and it says that `Module (project A) has no exported member Column`

Any idea how to fix this in IDE?

Answer (score 0):

`package.json` exists for a reason! You can make sure the TypeORM version in both projects is the same by forcing the installation of the same version in both of them!